# APEX SELECT LIST unwanted value

Tags: oracle-apex, selectlist

I have a select list that insists on display an numeric extra value, based on an id. I didn't get this issue with another select lists.

The basic query is

```
 select description,id 
 from situation 
 where ID = 2 and user_id = 1

 UNION

 select description,id 
 from situation 
 where ID = 3 OR ID = 4 and user_id = 5
```

The select list get an numeric value that represents the previous id from the query. I have tried with a simple query but doesn't work. 
When i try it on sql command, works fine.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: in the option `Display extra values` set it to `NO`.

Comment: Hi brenners, unfortunatly this option doesn't appear on page. I changed to a NULL or ITEM field type and it works.